# Why magit use rectangle on origin/master and not only on master?

Tags: magit, git

[image]

I have done a branch checkout on `master` but magit rectangle is on `origin/master` and not only on master.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the manual:

Magit displays references in logs a bit differently from how Git does
it.

Local branches are blue and remote branches are green.  Of course that
depends on the used theme, as do the colors used for other types of
references.  The current branch has a box around it, as do remote
branches that are their respective remote's `HEAD` branch.

If a local branch and its push-target point at the same commit, then
their names are combined to preserve space and to make that
relationship visible.  For example:

```
origin/feature
[green][blue-]
```

instead of

```
feature origin/feature
[blue-] [green-------]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I am not clear why on all projects the rectangle is only on [master] while here on [origin / master] (I moved the repo from gitlab to github, maybe it matters)